# Addthis Twitter Share Button

Tags: php, share, addthis

I 'm doing php web site. I want to add twitter, facebook share buttons. https://www.addthis.com/get/sharing#.URjSLWduKdk I want to use like this link. But there is some problems. I added that link's code to my web site. But I did not seem anything on my web site. For example; when user clicks twitter share button our text, our link, via tag will create directly. Please help me.

Comment: You need to link to your site or we can't help, you haven't added a proper description of your problem

Comment: Can you show us the page where it does not work? What browsers have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing so much issues with one service, you can try other services like sharethis, loginradius and others...market is full of such services

Answer (score 0):

The HTML will only display the links, the Javascript does all the API stuff, like sending data to the twitter service.

Have you added the javascript code too?

```
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_pinterest_pinit"></a>
<a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-51221ce07ff0d8f1"></script>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
```